# GET uri query with a json for Flask-Restless

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

In the Flask-Restless documentation, ("Making search queries") we can find that quering the framework in a special uri format que can query the database.

[Flask-Restless](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchformat.html)

```
http://localhost:5000/api/person?q={"filters":[{"name": "age", "op": "ge", "val": 10}]}
http://localhost:5000/api/person?q={"filters":[{"name": "age", "op": "ge", "val": 10},{"name": "age", "op": "le", "val": 20}]}
...
```

How can I do GET queries like that with jQuery.ajax or XMLHttpRequest in a simple way?

I've tried encoding with jQuery.param(), encondeURI + JSON.stringify()...

Sorry, this must be something really evident but i can't get it working.

```
 var url = "http://localhost:5000/api/person?";
 var obj = {"filters":[{"name": "age", "op": "ge", "val": 10}]};
 var jsn = JSON.stringify(obj);
 var encuri = encodeURI(url + "q=" + jsn); //NOPE
 var par = jQuery.param(jsn); //NOPE
 var raw = XMLHttpRequest();raw.open("GET", url + "q=" + encuri);raw.send() //NOPE
 ...
```

**SOLUTION**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/user',
    data: "q=" + JSON.stringify({"single":true,"filters":[{"name": "id", "op": "eq", "val": 1}]}),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});
```

Comment: Do you mind rephrasing your question? I can see the intended goal of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'blah',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});
```

You'll need json2.js (and jquery) included on the page.

Comment: `$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/user',
    data: "q=" + JSON.stringify({"single":true,"filters":[{"name": "id", "op": "eq", "val": -1}]}),
    dataType: 'json',
    type:"GET",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});` This seems to work. Thanks

Comment: what about: ```var data = encodeURIComponent("q="+JSON.stringify({"foo":"bar"}));```

Comment: Jquery uri encodes for you already. It will probably help to take a look at the source for $.ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'm fairly certain that those queries need to be escaped.

Assuming the URI's are encoded correctly (see encodeURI and encodeURIComponent), you should be able do jQuery.parseJSON.